Cant send data to destination page using compact
I've already passed data to the destination page using compact by a method. now I want to pass data to the destination page using compact again. Is there any problem for that? Firstly I tried to use one method instead of two method to send data using compact. but there was an argument error. Now when I tried to fetch data using second method still an error occurs which is unidentified variable. how do I solve the issue.
here is controller :
First method. Which is worked already.
public function doctors()
    {
        // Fetch all doctor information
        $doctor_info = addDoctor::all();
        return view('/Doctors/doctors',compact('doctor_info'));
    }

Second Method : Not working
public function edit($id){
        $to_be_edited = addDoctor::find($id);
        return view('/Doctors/doctors',compact('to_be_edited'));
}

Destination Page :

Error : $to_be_edited undefined variable

seems you using same view for both ? /Doctors/doctors use correct view file

@Hamelraj yes using same view. cause i want to sent data to the same page... any alternatives?

when you access function doctors() you have variable name $to_be_edited so you are getting error. i feel you trying wrong way ? can you explain more and show your full view code so can help

Just a note, but /Doctors/doctors is not the proper way to load a view. It should be in dot notation, like doctors.doctors where the file is /resources/doctors/doctors.blade.php

If you want to use the same view for both endpoints, then you need to either keep the variables the same (which could cause other issues as one is a collection and the other is a model), or add a check to see if $to_be_edited is not empty.

@Hamelraj still same problem - '$to_be_edited' inidentified
here is the code. kindly check : https://github.com/Azinkia-Prince/DMS.git

@Mr.Anonymous can you show me the error which line or page you get this undefined variable error ?
